# How to apply paint effects with PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, symbology

I would like to apply an inverted polygon style, including opacity and inner shadow using PyQGIS. 
So far, everything works except for the inner shadow effect. I found in the QGIS API that there is a class named QgsShadowEffect, but I do not get it to work.

The code looks like this:

```py
#Open layer
poly_1_link = r"...\Polygon_0.shp"
poly_1 = iface.addVectorLayer(poly_1_link, "", "ogr")

##Edit layer style##
#Define layer renderer
rend = poly_1.renderer()
print(rend.type())

#Define symbol from renderer
some_symbol = rend.symbol()

#Define symbology
some_symbol.setColor(QColor.fromRgb(255,0,0))   #Colour
some_symbol.setOpacity(0.5)                     #Opacity

#Apply shadow
#...

#Create an inverted polygon 
sub_rend = QgsInvertedPolygonRenderer().convertFromRenderer(rend)
poly_1.setRenderer(sub_rend)

#Update layer
poly_1.triggerRepaint()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of adding paint effects is to add another symbol layer for it. Here is a code snippet to produce following polygon.

[image: Polygon with inner shadow]

```
#Add layer
coords = [(20, 60), (32, 60), (32, 70), (20, 70), (20, 60)]   
polygon = QgsGeometry.fromPolygonXY( [[ QgsPointXY( pair[0], pair[1] ) for pair in coords ]] ) 
layer = QgsVectorLayer("Polygon?crs=EPSG:4326", "polygon_0", "memory")
feature = QgsFeature()
feature.setGeometry(polygon)
provider = layer.dataProvider()
layer.startEditing()
provider.addFeatures( [feature] )
layer.commitChanges()

##Edit layer style##
symbol = layer.renderer().symbol()

#Define symbology
symbol.setColor(QColor.fromRgb(255,0,0))
symbol.setOpacity(0.5)

#Apply shadow
inner_shdw = QgsInnerShadowEffect()
inner_shdw_layer = QgsSimpleFillSymbolLayer()
inner_shdw_layer.setPaintEffect(inner_shdw)
symbol.appendSymbolLayer(inner_shdw_layer)

QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
```